# Works in Experimental Instance but not Normal Instance

Tags: roslyn

I've created a couple of code diagnostic analyser and a colourisation which are packaged into a single VSIX. This VSIX works perfectly in the Experimental instance of visual studio, the diagnostic analyser and colourisation works.

So decide to installing it into the non-Experimenatlal (the default one) instance.
It installs, appears in the list of extension and is enabled.

Everything appears fine but the analysers and colourisation ain't working?

Any ideas of what could be the cause?

Using the VS2015 preview.

I have tried restarting VS2015 it still doesn't work.

Comment: First; get an ActivityLog.xml for VS2015 preview, secondly, try if your vsix works for another VS2015 preview in other computer. Use virtual machine, if you don't have any other.

Comment: Try following these steps to see if there are first-chance exceptions that you're missing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/02/08/how-to-investigate-and-report-visual-studio-issues.aspx

It's likely your extension is interfering with some other extension. Hard to say without an exception call stack, but you'll likely have a first-chance exception if you attach a debugger to the main-hive VS.

Comment: Issue is it can't find a file, that is include with the VSIX. That file get installed into the directory of the vsix. But can't be found.
So I need a way, to locate the file in code.